# Bad filedescriptor error handling

Tags: c, sockets, unix, posix, errno

I am  practicing POSIX programming sockets and I have following problem with my server, when i terminate one of its clients, the function pselect gets error bad filedescriptor (I think its errno=EBADF), could you help me and write how can I avoid it in my code?

Here is what i wrote:

```
void doServer(int fd) {
//fd is the listening socket (there is only one)
int maxfd = fd;
//base, and reading fd set
fd_set base_rfds, rfds;
int i;
sigset_t mask, oldmask;
//zero out base fd set
FD_ZERO(&base_rfds);
//add listening socket to base fd set
FD_SET(fd, &base_rfds);
//add SIGINT to blocking signal mask
sigemptyset (&mask);
sigaddset (&mask, SIGINT);
sigprocmask (SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &oldmask);
//main server loop (block on pselect untill fd changes or we get signal)
while(!stop){
    rfds=base_rfds;
    //call pselect with oldmask to not block SIG_INT
    if(pselect(maxfd+1,&rfds,NULL,NULL,NULL,&oldmask)>0){

        if(FD_ISSET(fd,&rfds)){
            //connect client
            maxfd+=add_new_client(fd, &base_rfds);
            //remove listening socket from reading fd set
            FD_CLR(fd,&rfds);
        }
        //remove listening socket from base fd set
        FD_CLR(fd,&base_rfds);
        handle_connection(rfds,&base_rfds,maxfd);
        //add listening socket back into base fd set
        FD_SET(fd,&base_rfds);
    }
    else{
        if(EINTR==errno) continue;
        ERR("select");
    }
}
//close all of fd's from connected clients
for(i=0;i<maxfd;i++) 
    if(FD_ISSET(i,&base_rfds) && TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(close(i))<0)ERR("close");
sigprocmask (SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL);
}
```

**EDIT:**
here is add_new_client function:

```
int add_new_client(int sfd, fd_set *base_rfds){
int nfd,new_flags;
//accept now if we can (non-blocking)
if((nfd=TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(accept(sfd,NULL,NULL)))<0) {
    if(EAGAIN==errno||EWOULDBLOCK==errno) return 0;
    ERR("accept");
}
//remember to make the fd non-blocking
//get current flags, add O_NONBLOCK
new_flags = fcntl(nfd, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK;
//apply new flags
fcntl(nfd, F_SETFL, new_flags);
//add discriptor to base fd set
FD_SET(nfd,base_rfds);
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you print out the value of `maxfd` when you get the pselect failure?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes I can, but this fd is no longer valid since client closed.

Comment: What I'd like to see is whether `maxfd` ever gets to be larger than the size of an `fd_set`. Does `add_new_client` always return a positive number? Then maxfd will never decrease.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes add_new_client returns always 1 or 0 if(EAGAIN==errno||EWOULDBLOCK==errno) return 0;

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting on a socket that you have closed. When you close a socket you need to remove it from the FD set. Your handling of this set seems pretty optimistic. For example, you can't be sure that adding a new client is really going to increment the maximum FD. I also don't understand why you're removing the listening socket from the set once, let alone twice, and then reinstating it. You need to look at some sample code for `select()`. This is all very strange.